# How to use a parameter

Tags: aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a Step Output containing `{"hello": "wold"}` and my `pythonshell` had this output as Step Input showing up in the State Machine Graph.

I want to print the value `world` by using the key `hello` in a `pythonshell` job

This is the code I have now and it is not working, I get the error that the argument `watisdit` is expected:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions


def main():
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'watisdit'])
    print('watisdit: ' + str(args['watisdit']))
    print('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
    print('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glue job expects argument keys starting with '--'. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html) for reference.

For your current code your argument must contain: `{"--hello": "wold"}`

and the code will be:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'hello'])
print("The value for hello is:" , args['hello'])
```